# Delete Bookmarks in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, delete, bookmarks

How can I delete the bookmarks from Chrome in Ubuntu(the right click would enable us to do this in Windows)?

Comment: Right-click and choosing Delete does work for Chrome in Ubuntu.  Are you looking to delete them all at one time or one by one?  Or do you want to delete the `Bookmarks` file itself?

Comment: No.. I just want to delete one at a time . Right click doesn't works in ubuntu . right?

Comment: @Terrance But it isnt working on my system ... do we need to enable it or something .. nad if you are talking about  "shift+10" , it isnt popping the "delete bookmark" option for that.

Comment: First of all, unless you are able to select that bookmark and not just highlight it with a mouse, Shift+F10 is only still working in the active application.  Secondly, what version of Ubuntu are you using?  Is it a clean install or an upgrade?  I am asking this because recently I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 and right click stopped working and I had many other problems with it.  I had to clean install for everything to work.

Comment: @Terrance Oh! MIne is Ubuntu 18. So this version doesn't have Right clicks? Is it?

Comment: It does have right click.  How did you install Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: With a bootable Pen Drive .